# Loading Weights for layer containing layers of a pretrained model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, object-detection

i've been experimenting with object detectors in tensorflow(v.2.14)Thanks in advance for your help!
Best regards, Erik
recently and got stuck at the point where i want to transfer learn with models of mine.

I trained a CNN Object detector with the structure

```py
model
    -layer_old_1
    -layer_old_2
    -layer_old_3
    -layer_old_4
    -...
```

Now i want to transfer the weights of the pretrained CNN detector in a new model with structure

```py
model
    -encoder_layer
        -layer_old_1
        -layer_old_2
        -layer_old_3
    -decoder_layer
        -layer_new_1
        -layer_new_2
        -layer_new_3
```

My weigths of the old model are saved in a `weights.hdf5` file.

I got multiple challenges at once:

1. I need to load weights for a layer, not the complete model. Usually, I would use load_weigths with the option "by_name", but since my old layers are incorporated into the `encoder_layer` I reckon the names have changed (from `layer_old_1` to `encoder_layer/layer_old_1`).
2. I cut off some layers of the previously trained model. If i dont use the option "by_name",  which does not exist in `set_weights` for layers, I would most likely have a mismatch of weight sizes

My only viable Idea until now is to retrain the old model and adapt its structure to

```py
model
    -encoder_layer
        -layer_old_1
        -layer_old_2
        -layer_old_3
        -layer_old_4
        -...
```

which would result in a giant loss of time